# How do you say "translation" in Koine Greek?

Tags: greek, word-request

I'm looking for a Koine Greek word that means "translation". When I say "translation", I'm referring to a translation of a text in a foreign language. So the context would be the translation of a Koine Greek text into English.

What Koine Greek word denotes such a translation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ἑρμηνεία can have this meaning. The [LSJ entry](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3De(rmhnei%2Fa) has some Koine-relevant attestations:

> 3. translation, Aristeas 3, Ph.2.141; “ἑ. τῶν Π̔ωμαϊκῶν” POxy.1201.12 (iii A.D.); ἑ. ἔχειν to mean when translated, Ph.1.232, Porph.Plot.17.

Comment: Thank you, TKR! Good to see you on this forum. ἑρμηνεία evokes the English word *hermeneutics*, making both the Greek word and its definition easy to remember.

Comment: So, would that be ἑρμηνεία, 'clarification,' when translating from Greek? but  something else, say τα τοῦ μεταφραστοῦ, when translating into Greek?

Comment: @Hugh I don't know that there were separate terms for translating into and out of Greek -- what makes you think so?

Comment: If someone translated something **into** Greek for me, I could see that as a change of phrasing μεταφράζειν ( the word used by Josephus and by Plutarch for translate); but the not as elucidation ' ἑρμηνεία'

Answer (score 3):

Being Greek I may be also able to help. Ερμηνεία is a very formal way to denote 'translation'. I would say that in common (Κοινά) Greek, the word translation would be μετάφραση.

Comment: Thanks and welcome to the site! To clarify, the question is about ancient Greek (modern Greek questions are off-topic here).